# How to SUCCESSFULLY add a code section to an executable file in Linux?

Tags: binary-analysis, linux, elf, executable, binary-format

I am in Linux, and I have seen this question a few times but never, nobody answered how to really make this work.

I need to add a section to an already compiled binary. Lets say for a moment is an **ELF** file. I'm using **objcopy** so this should be generic for any format because **objcopy** uses **libbfd** that handles many formats.

My process is as follows.

I create the bytecode for a section I want to append to an already compiled ELF file. Let's name this file bytecode.bin

Then I do:

```
objcopy --add-section .mysection=bytecode.bin \
--set-section-flags .mysection=code,contents,alloc,load,readonly \
myprogram myprogram_edited
```

Then I adjust the VMA of the secition:

```
objcopy --adjust-section-vma .mysection=$((16#XXXXX)) myprogram_edited myprogram_edited
```

Where XXXXXX is the new VMA address for the section.

I get the warning:

```
objcopy: stIbZt3t: warning: allocated section `.mysection' not in segment
```

When I do:

```
objdump -d myprogram_edited
```

I see:

```
Disassembly of section .mysection:

0000000000201011 <.mysection>:
...
...
```

So I see the section is created OK and the VMA adjusted. But the section is not mapped to segments, so it can't be loaded at runtime.

How can I solve this?

EDIT:

I opted for using Intel's [PIN](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) tool. Very useful and powerful for RI and binary injection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`libbfd` is not a magic wand, it is in fact pretty limited (it's one of the reasons why GDB cannot debug files without a section table). In particular, `objcopy` won't add PHT entries for you, so you will have to extend or adjust the PHT manually. You can either do it manually with a hex editor or try using a library such as `libelf` (it gives you necessary primitives but you'll need to implement the logic yourself).

Comment: "it's one of the reasons why GDB cannot debug files without a section table" - thats something I've been wondering about for a while. Thanks for mentioning this

Comment: The problem is, I need some generic tool that handles more executable file formats, not only ELF. But I think it is already a nice problem with ELF only.

Comment: Well, I'm not aware of any such tool so I guess you'll have to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can look at LIEF:

GitHub page: https://github.com/lief-project/LIEF

Site: https://lief.quarkslab.com

Comment: Your answer would be much more valuable if you can provide a basic example on how to code what is asked in LIEF.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using [Intel PIN](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool)

Edit:
I know this isn't actually an answer to the question. I was trying to change the behavior of a native executable and thought that I needed to change the binary on disk, when actually a binary instrumentation tool was enough for my purpuse.

Comment: well, PIN doesn't "add a section to an already compiled binary", so this is not an answer to the question as it was stated.

Comment: Well, I was so ignorant back then I event didn't know what I needed.

Comment: Congratulations on discovering [XY questions](https://xyproblem.info)